# Accessing a remote filesystem with powershell - Issues with PSDrive

Tags: powershell, ibm-ifs, new-psdrive

I'm trying to automate a process of editing a text file on a remote system every morning.

My script:

```
$User = "USER"
$File = "C:\secureString.txt"
$c = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
 -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString)

New-PSDrive -Name "X" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\192.168.1.69\ifs\home" -Credential $c
(Get-Content X:\textFile.txt).Replace(","," ") | Set-Content X:\textFile.TXT
```

Now, this worked flawlessly at first, but a few days later I'm hit with this error:

```
New-PSDrive : Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again
```

Couple key things that make this tricky:

- The remote system is not windows. (IFS of an AS400)
- The IFS is reachable from the windows machine running the script. (I can browse the IFS with windows explorer by entering the IP.)
- The remote system requires credentials to access. (The credentials for an AS400 user.)
- I cant pull the file off the IFS, edit locally on windows, then put it back.

Is there a better way to do this?
If not, how can I correct the multi connections error and prevent it from happening again?

I sure someone will ask 'why dont you edit the file on the 400??' I likely will. There were some issues with that which is why I tried powershell in the first place. This was *suppose to* a 5 min deal but think I just overcomplicated things instead.

Comment: You create a psdrive `X`, but never remove it after your work is done with `Remove-PSDrive`

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37728594/45375) helps. As for the error message: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/cannot-connect-to-network-share